# Usage difference between Apache and Apache Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat

As Tomcat is a widely used java web server, and Apache is also a web server, what's the different between them in real project usage?

After some research, I got a simple idea like,

Apache Tomcat <=> For java fans

Apache <=> More general web server, eg. PHP:XAMPP,LAMP

Comment: Quick answer is Tomcat is a servlet container and web server, and hence can host java web applications while Apache is just a web server.

Answer (score 3):

The differences between Apache and Apache Tomcat are:

Apache:

1. It is developed in C.
2. It is an HTTP server. That means that it serves files through HTTP protocol.
3. It can host applications coded in any programming languages, not just Java.
4. It is capable of request/response processing and load balancing.
5. It can generally handle requests for static html pages. However, it can still handle dynamic requests for pages coded in languages like PHP, Perl and Ruby.

Apache Tomcat:

1. It is developed in Java.
2. It is a JSP/Servlet container. That means it handles the lifecycle for servlets.
3. It is supposed to host applications those are coded in Java. However, it can also execute Perl scripts.
4. Beyond the basic request/response processing, it can also manage the entire JSP/Servlet lifecycle.
5. It can handle both static and dynamic content. The static page are generated using HTML, while the dynamic content are generated using Servlet and JSP.

Answer (score -1):

Apache is more for a static web site with basic functions.
Apache tomcat is container above Apache which can used with Java backend project.

They can be used separately or run together.

Comment: "Apache is more for a static web site with basic functions" — [1](http://php.net/manual/en/security.apache.php), [2](http://perl.apache.org/), [3](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/), [4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) — It really isn't. If you just want to serve static files, then Apache HTTPD is probably overkill.

Comment: "container above Apache " — What does that even mean? It's a completely separate piece of software.

Answer (score -1):

**Apache** - It's a web server, which helps in serving static content mostly. But, it can also handle dynamic requests for pages coded in languages like PHP, Perl and Ruby.

**Tomcat** - It's an application server, which helps in deploying dynamic content using Java.

**Apache Tomcat** - Here, both are used in conjunction where Apache serves static content, and forwarding the requests for dynamic content to Tomcat.

*Content refers to web pages.*

Comment: No, not true at all. Apache serves only static content? How did you figure that out?

Comment: I read it somewhere on internet, can suggest an edit to improve the answer ?